# Алиасы, почему у меня работает первый импорт, а второй нет?

Tags: javascript, typescript

подскажите, имеется следующая структура
корневая папка=>src=>shared=>index.ts я не понимаю, почему у меня работает первый импорт, а второй нет - в чем загвоздка?

```
import { RouteName } from '@shared'   не работает
Cannot find module '@shared' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
import { RouteName } from '@/shared'  работает
```

tsconfig.json

```
 "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["./src/shared/*"],
    }
```

webpack.config.ts

```
alias: {
      '@': options.paths.src,
      '@shared': `${options.paths.src}/shared`,
    },
```

index.ts

```
export * from './config'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"@shared/*": ["./src/shared/*"],
        ^--------------------------- этот слеш обязателен в импорте
```

Пропиши так:

```
"@share*": ["./src/share*"],
```

Comment: `"@shared": ["./src/shared/*"]`,
            также выдает ошибку
`Cannot find module '@shared/' or its corresponding type declarations.`
Пропиши так:

    "@shared": ["./src/shared/*"],

Comment: @Jesys_cyclist, блин, я звёздочку посеял. А вот `d` я выкинул намеренно, но может быть с ним тоже работает. Ответ обновлён.